# Load X509 certificates from Azure

Tags: azure, x509certificate, client-certificates

We have a standard Azure account and have uploaded client certificates but aren't able to find them.

Have been following the guide at: https://azure.microsoft.com/sv-se/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/

What I've done:

1. Uploaded all the certificates in the certificate section in our Azure account.
2. Added "WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES" with value "*" to the App Settings section.

The code we are using to load a certificate:

```
X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "THE_THUMBPRINT", false);
```

The "certCollection" is empty. I've also loaded all certificates to a "X509Store" with various parameters i.e

```
X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
```

But can't find the certificates I've uploaded. Does anyone have any idea what we could try or are we missing something?

Comment: Could you find any solution?

Comment: Yes it turned out that we did have a Shared account. In order for the certificates to work you need to have at least a Standard or Premium account.